# Two way authentication okta testing?

Tags: c#

I am not sure if this is possible. I was task of getting an access token from okta. The problem is okta is using a two way authentication system where it will send a push notification on your phone and you will have to click the button yes on notification. Is this possible to automate in test to get the access token? First time doing some test automation so my experience is very limited. Anyone?

Comment: Two *factor* authentication?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah